# Out-of-browser specific settings do not affect in-browser applications : IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, silverlight-5.0

Im performing a print functionality from Silverlight 5 inside a web project. the  document to be printed is created dynamically in the silverlight project. the problem is in IE 11 browser i get the following error Out-of-browser specific settings do not affect in-browser applications.

the Out of browser settings were set correctly. as below.

```
<OutOfBrowserSettings ShortName="EmployeeSchedule Application" EnableGPUAcceleration="False" ShowInstallMenuItem="True">
  <OutOfBrowserSettings.Blurb>EmployeeSchedule Application on your desktop; at home, at work or on the go.</OutOfBrowserSettings.Blurb>
  <OutOfBrowserSettings.WindowSettings>
    <WindowSettings Title="EmployeeSchedule Application" />
  </OutOfBrowserSettings.WindowSettings>
  <OutOfBrowserSettings.SecuritySettings>
    <SecuritySettings ElevatedPermissions="NotRequired" />
  </OutOfBrowserSettings.SecuritySettings>
  <OutOfBrowserSettings.Icons />
</OutOfBrowserSettings>
```

any idea where the error could be ? any refrence would be appreciated.